# How do you interact with the armory?

Tags: running-with-rifles

So there's armory locations near some of the bases.  You can bring enemy cargo trucks to them to unlock new gear, and you can also apparently use them as a shop to spend your RP on new gear for yourself.

> You can buy and sell weapons, items, wearables (type II vest) at an armory. It's basically a shop. The currency used at the armory are RP or Resource points. If you are from the Greenbelts faction, armories don't sell Greycollar or Brownpants' equipment. And vice versa with other factions as most equipment is faction specific. If you find any valuables, for example a beer can, a cigarette package, etc you can exchange those at the armory for RP or Resource points.
>
> There is usually one armory every 2-3 bases.

Problem is, I don't see how to actually interact with the armory.  I looked through the controls menu and there was no entry for 'entry armory' or anything similar.

How do I use the armory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is quite old, but for the record, you can just hold down the key to pick up an item (I think 'F' is the default) when standing in front of the armory to buy/sell items.  There will be a tooltip popup that will appear when you are close enough to the armory.